# Chosen select work on chrome but not firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I load options from a database into a chosen select with angularjs, the code works as expected on chrome browsers but  on firefox or internet explorer the code doesn't load the options.

I tried to switch from a directive to the angular chosen library, this one works on all browser but the ng-change doesn't triggers the function associated to the event.

This is my original code(work on chrome only): 
HTML

```
       <select ng-model="addCapas" ng-change="aplicarFiltro()" 
            multiple class="control-group html-multi-chosen-select" 
            multiple="multiple" chosen style="width: 100%;">

      <option ng-repeat="filt in filtros"  value={{filt.nombre}}>{{filt.nombre}}</option>                       

    </select>
```

the js file:

```
App.directive('chosen', function($timeout) {
    var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {

        scope.$watch('', function() {
            $timeout(function() {
                element.trigger('chosen:updated');
            }, 0, false);
        }, true);
        $timeout(function() {
            element.chosen();
        }, 0, false);
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker
    };
});
```

the part i load the options on the select:

```
App.controller("appCtrl", function ($http,$scope) {


    $http({url: "/ewisemaps/catalogoComp",
        data: $.param({
            catalogo: "Capas",
        }),
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).success(function (res) {

        if(res!=null){              
            $scope.filtros = [];
            $scope.capas = [];
            $scope.addTipolog = [];
            angular.forEach(res.oapi, function (index, value) {
                if(index.tipo == 1){
                    $scope.filtros.push({id: index.id, nombre: index.nombre, valor: index.valor, orden: index.orden});              
                    $scope.capas.push(index.nombre);
                }else{
                    $scope.addTipolog.push({id: index.id, nombre: index.nombre, valor: index.valor, orden: index.orden});
                }           
            });         
            console.log("Carga de capas completa");     


        }else{
            console.log("Error al cargar catalogos\n");
        }
    });
```

When i use the chosen angular i change the module code to this : `var App = angular.module('App', ['localytics.directives']);` and delete my chosen directive.

any hints on why only works on chrome? or why chosen angular doesn't trigger the ng-change event?

**Edit:** Added the server site you can test it
http://192.168.15.100:8008/ewisemaps/capas

Comment: What is the purpose of the ng-change function?

Comment: @gr3g update some wms layers

Comment: I was looking for an answer, but @Zachary Elias is right; It is written in the angular-chose lib. Do you wan't to know why this isn't working inside the lib?

Comment: I am using angular-chosen with `ng-change` and it works as expected! Does it work if you try it without the `multiple` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [angular-chosen docs](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen):

> Note: don't try to use ngModel with ngRepeat. It won't work. Use ngOptions. It's better that way.

This implies that using ng-repeat for your select tag is likely to cause unexpected behavior -- for example, across different browsers.

Try getting rid of your option tag and just use ng-options:

```
   <select ng-model="addCapas" 
           ng-options="filtro for filtro in filtros"
           ng-change="aplicarFiltro()" 
           multiple class="control-group html-multi-chosen-select" 
           multiple="multiple" chosen style="width: 100%;"                      
   </select>
```

FYI: your link to the server site won't work on StackOverflow. You can only connect directly to an IP address if you're on the same area network as the computer trying to connect.

Comment: @i tried that, but then the ng-change event doesn't work